# Как достать значения из строки, разделенная тегами?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно узнать значение из строчки `String`, значения разделены `тегами`.

**Вот пример:**

Строчка:  `<time><days>0</days> день, <hours>0</hours> час, <minutes>2</minutes></time> минут назад`

Мне надо то что записано в `<days>0</days>` записать в переменную `int days`, а то что в `<hours>0</hours>` в `int hours`, а `<minutes>2</minutes>` в `int minutes`.

**В итоге должно получится:** 

`int days=0;
int hours=0;
int minutes=2;`

Как все это можно сделать? Была идея деления строк, но думаю найдется идея получше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую воспользоваться регулярками:

```
    String s = "<time><days>0</days> день, <hours>0</hours> час, <minutes>2</minutes></time> минут назад";

    //  Создаём паттерн для вытаскивания значения тега <time>
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<time>(?<timeVar>.*)</time>"); 

    //  Создаём для него объект Matcher, который пройдёт регуляркой по строке
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    //  Ищем первое вхождение регулярки
    m.find();   

    //  Достаём именованную переменную из регулярки
    String time = m.group("timeVar");   

    //  Далее всё так же, только используем строку, найденную на предыдущем этапе
    p = Pattern.compile("<days>(?<daysVar>\\d+)</days>.*<hours>(?<hoursVar>\\d+)</hours>.*<minutes>(?<minutesVar>\\d+)</minutes>");
    m = p.matcher(time);
    m.find();

    int days = Integer.parseInt(m.group("daysVar"));
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(m.group("hoursVar"));
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group("minutesVar"));

    System.out.println(days);
    System.out.println(hours);
    System.out.println(minutes);
```

По-хорошему вы должны завернуть вызов `m.find()` в условную конструкцию if, но если вы уверены, что входные данные верны, этого можно не делать.

И да, сразу скажу, что такой регулярке подсовывать несколько подряд идущих тегов `time` не надо, ибо первая регулярка завернёт всю строку и получится каша.

Также вы можете поискать парсер xml, который сделает эту же работу, но, если есть регулярки, почему бы ими не пользоваться?)

Так как такие фишки с именованием работают только начиная с jdk 1.7, вот код, который будет работать и на более ранних версия jdk

```
    String s = "<time><days>0</days> день, <hours>0</hours> час, <minutes>2</minutes></time> минут назад";

    //  Создаём паттерн для вытаскивания значения тега <time>
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<time>(.*)</time>"); 

    //  Создаём для него объект Matcher, который пройдёт регуляркой по строке
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    //  Ищем первое вхождение регулярки
    m.find();   

    //  Достаём именованную переменную из регулярки
    String time = m.group(1);   

    //  Далее всё так же, только используем строку, найденную на предыдущем этапе
    p = Pattern.compile("<days>(\\d+)</days>.*<hours>(\\d+)</hours>.*<minutes>(\\d+)</minutes>");
    m = p.matcher(time);
    m.find();

    int days = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));

    System.out.println(days);
    System.out.println(hours);
    System.out.println(minutes);
```

Также можно две регулярки объединить в одну, поэтому если вы желаете, можете попрактиковаться с этим заданием, это не должно составить труда)

Comment: Интересно, об этом впервые слышу, буду знакомится с регулярками поближе) сейчас пойду тестить код...

Comment: Если я вам помог, я был бы рад получить плюсик и/или лучший ответ:) Спасибо.

Comment: Без награды не останетесь:) Вот щяс получил пару error от студии,

Comment: Error:(123, 24) error: no suitable method found for group(String)
method Matcher.group(int) is not applicable
(actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
method Matcher.group() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: У вас, похоже, неправильно скопипастился код. Перепроверьте

Comment: Нет, код скопировался правильно, точь в точь

Comment: Возьмите отсюда: http://pastebin.com/5bQ07F99

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27005/discussion-between-ploadyfree-and--).

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/CtK9Mq1aiU486

Comment: @ДенисКотляров войдите в чат